# Proof of exponential complex constant

Tags: complex-analysis

If we let

$ g(z) = e^{f(z)} $

and $f$ is holomorphic on a region G, how do we prove that $f$ is a constant if $g$ is a constant?

Do we just simply find the derivative of $g(z)$ and set it to zero, hence, a constant?
i.e. $g'(z) = e^{f(z)} f'(z) = 0 $

$-> $ $f'(z) = 0$ implies $f(z)=constant$ ?

Comment: Your proof (using derivatives) is correct, but holomorphic is actually a stronger request than needed. If $f$ is continuous, then the result also follows (via a slightly different proof).

Comment: @PedroM. i might have not understood your comment. what "result" follows? could you help me out on proving this?

Comment: I mean the following result: If $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous in a connected open set $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $g(z) = e^{f(z)}$ is constant, then $f$ is also a constant. The idea is that if $g(z_1) = g(z_2)$, then $f(z_1) - f(z_2) = 2k\pi i$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and continuous functions cannot "suddenly jump" $2\pi i$. Can you make this a more formal proof?

Comment: ok thanks! i will try.